# Django forms. How add, search data to form field from database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 models.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Reservation(models.Model)
    person = ForeiginKey(Perrson, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
```

I want make reservation.
How make form in order that first field "person" can search person and add found data to form field, if person not exist add new person.

Comment: use modelform and render them in template

Comment: Like an autocomplete for person field?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at [django smart selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) as it might come handy.

Your model would change as:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Reservation(models.Model)
    person = ChainedForeignKey(
           Person,
           chained_field="Person",
           chained_model_field="Person",
           show_all=False,
           auto_choose=True,
           sort=True)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
```

Next you'd create a form and render it in a template. Whenever you select a `person` in the form `reservation` field will update automatically.

Then use a view to handle your logic, `if person not exist add new person...`